# How do we return a boolean variable from a method?

Tags: java

I am trying to find the best way to write this method. One side we can assign a boolean variable with true and false value and return the value.

```
boolean methodName(..arguments) 
{
    boolean variableName=false;
    if(..check condition) 
    {
        variableName=false;
    }
    return variableName;
}
```

Another way is to return true or false directly without assigning it to any declared variable for example return true.

Comment: Why not simply `return (checkConditionHere);`??

Comment: in this method you are always returning `false` , in this case you can easily return `false` at the first line of method

Comment: It looks like you're asking whether you should use [a single `return` or multiple `return`s](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/118717/202685); there's no definitive answer, what I linked to is one examination, out of many.  If you're working on a pre-existing project, use whichever matches that project's style.  If you're working on your own project, use whichever you find more readable, but be consistent.  If you need cleanup code, use `finally` or single return.  And so on...

Comment: HI All, got some negative 9 number showing on my question. How do i get that corrected. stack overflow is not letting me post more question as it says i have to improve my question and i am not sure what does that mean. Neither am i able to delete my question to improve the score. @JustinTime-ReinstateMonica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple methods that do not have many checks on the Boolean conditions, it's usually fine to simply return `true` or `false`.

```
boolean methodName(..arguments) {
    return <checkCondition>
}
```

The above snippet is a reduction of your code's *intent* (I say *intent* because yours will always return false).

For more complex functions, a common rule of thumb is to assign a return variable, similar to what you've provided; having too many return statements can be harder to maintain.

This all said, it typically boils down to coding standards maintained by the software team.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use any variables for return true or false value.

This simple method will be looks like this:

```
boolean yourMethod(argument) {
    if (yourCondition)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

or more simply (and more correct):

```
boolean yourMethod(argument) {
    return (yourCondition);
}
```

For example. The user inputs word ("name" e.g.). And you need to check that he wrote exactly "name" using boolean method. Now you write this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // We create input stream reader and read input data.
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s = reader.readLine();

    // Now you check out that user wrote exactly your word ("name").
    boolean result = checkInputData(s);
}


// Create boolean method.
static boolean checkInputData(String arg) {
    return arg.equals("name");
}
```

And if the user had wrote "name", your variable **result** will be true. Else it will be false.

Answer (score -1):

Either assigning the true or false value to a variable or returning true or false do pretty much the same thing.  It depends on what makes sense in the scope of what's calling your method and how it's value is used.

Like the results from `five.checkToSeeIfItsFive();` might make more sense when you read it if it's just returning true, vs. returning a variable that contains the value of true.

Comment: "_It depends on what makes sense in the scope of what's calling your method..._". That is absolutely **false**. The calling method should not care or know the implementation details of how the called method is implemented.

Comment: I just meant for the sake of making it easier to read and understand in english, not how it actually works.

Comment: To me, if it returns true or false it's easier to read the code and seems simpler than returning something like booleanStatusVariable. But, in some situations it might make more sense to use a variable.